# How to change element style color

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and i am trying to change the color of a h1/h3 heading by css but i cant.

```
<div class="advisor-title-banner-header">
    <div class="hgroup">
        <a href="http://bashalaprairie.ca">
            <h1 style="color:#ffe2e2;">Basha La Prairie - (450) 444-1777</h1>
            <h3 style="color:#ffe2e2;">La meilleure cuisine libanaise</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem:

```
element.style {
    color: #ffe2e2;
}
```

i want to change the color to red. I tried:

```
.element.style {
    color: red important!;
}
```

but it wouldnt work.

website: www.bashalaprairie.ca

I want to change the text color of Basha la prairie (450) 444-1777 - la meilleur cuisine lebanese from white to red

thanks!!!

Comment: `advisor-title-banner-header a * { color: red !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS rule isn't working because the exclamation mark goes on the other way of the `important` keyword:

Example:

```
element.style {
    color: red !important;
}
```

You also have to specify your element. For a h2, the rule should look like this:

```
h2.yourSpecificClass {
    color: red !important;
}
```

In addition, you have an extra dot (`.`) before your second example.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [CSS Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

To create a CSS to change the color of ALL h2 you could write

```
h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

If you want to be more specific you can add class selectors `.classname` and other things to narrow down to the single element.

Also it is `!important` instead of the way you wrote.